# fadeslideshow jquery ready conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict, ready

When we add fadslideshow to our home page our category boxes display different.

Correct display of our category boxes(scroll down page to see the category boxes) https://pretty.alkoncgi.mobi/index-3.php

After we add fadeslideshow.js(scroll down page to see the category boxes) https://pretty.alkoncgi.mobi/index.php

Answer (score 0):

found the issue. in fadeslideshow.js I removed the line jQuery.noConflict()